# weird Altera simulation result

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, flipflop

I am trying to build a T flip-flop from a D flip-flop. The D flip-flop looks like this 
[image]

and the simulated waveform shows that it works.(when there is a rising edge D will be passed to Q)
[image]

So I started building a T flip-flop by connecting Qnot to D (I am expecting every clock rising edge Q will be toggled because Qnot is passed to Q)
[image]

but the simulated waveform looks like this
[image]

Q will oscillate when CLK is low. One oscillation period is around couple ns.
I played with different Clear and Preset signals but it still happens.

If anyone can point out my errors.
Thanks.

Comment: The first thing is not a FF, it's a latch.

Answer (score 3):

The first schematic shows a latch rather than a D flip-flop -- it forwards D to Q when CLK is high. Q maintains its value for CLK low.

This would almost explain the behavior of your latter circuit. Q should remain constant when CLK is low. It will forward !Q when CLK is high and therefore oscillate.

Why the oscillation happens with CLK low I cannot explain (perhaps the two screenshots are inconsistent?).

Comment: The first circuit is indeed a latch. Sorry I was confused. But I took the screen shots after I compiled two circuits with no errors. Still struggling with the oscillation.

Comment: So would Q oscillate when CLK is high because !Q is passed to Q continuously as long as CLK is high? It looks like I cannot build a T flip-flop from it then...

Answer (score 1):

When the clock is HIGH there seems to be a race hazard through the circuit which causes a rapid oscillation.

Lets assume the starting condition is Q = 0  (NOT Q = 1)

[image]

when the clock signal goes  HIGH

```
                        a b c d e f g
                        1   1 0
```

**g** will go low causing **d** to go high causing **c** to go low causing **g** to go high and so on and so forth

when clock is low

```
                        a b c d e f g
                        0   1 0
```

**f** is low, **b** is high, **c** is high the system is stable

Comment: Thanks for walking it through. Your analysis is right. My implementation to build a T flip-flop is incorrect because the toggle happens too much when CLK is high.

Comment: Timtianyang - your very welcome, good luck with you next implementation